# How to clean an Iberital MC2/Challenge grinder that is stuck?

Tags: grinder, maintenance

I have an [Iberital MC2/Challenge grinder](http://www.iberital.com/en/coffee-grinder/challenge/manual/) which got stuck today while grinding. Not sure what happened.

In the manual, I can't see how I can clean the inside of the grinding mechanism. Does anyone know how to take of the top grinding plate so that I can clean all residue from it?

Comment: Would you mind describing specifically what you mean by 'stuck'? Does the grinder look jammed and the burrs stop moving? Do you hear no sound completely signifying motor failure? Do you hear the motor but no coffee is being ground?

Answer (score 3):

A couple useful posts found in a thread linked below.  Text below is two user posts.  LeeWardles post seems to have been accepted by the original poster as being correct information, but you can check out the whole thread below.

[CoffeeForumsUK](https://coffeeforums.co.uk/showthread.php?1669-Problem-with-Iberital-MC2)

awlred posted:

> I have an MC2 and recently pulled it out after my newer grinder
>   breaking down. You can pop the top bit off the grinder (The black
>   plastic part) and unscrew the worm-drive mounting. Doing this makes it
>   very easy to get access to the top burr plate and unscrew it until it
>   comes away. After that use a stiff bristled toothbrush or small
>   paintbrush to remove all the ground coffee etc and clean the housing
>   out entirely.
>
> Assembly is the opposite of dismantling. As a rule of thumb I tighten
>   until the burrs meet (the lower burr moves with the upper) and then
>   loosen off about 1/8th of a full turn.
>
> Point to note The wormdrive, while being annoyingly slow to adjust
>   needs to be in place for the grinder to remain dialed at any setting.
>
> While on the subject, an easy hack to make adjustments quicker is a
>   set of locking pliers (welders pliers) either around the knob or
>   straight on the bar. Which makes the whole process a LOT quicker, if
>   slightly less elegant.

LeeWardle posted:

> just needs a strip down. From what you have said it sounds like the
>   grind is set to course (after you wound it back) so the noise is bean
>   fragments. Also could be that one if the screws has come loose so the
>   blde is loose on its mount.
>
> Hold the button down that holds the step ring and unscrew the ring.
>   This will leave you with the plastic ring and an cast alu mount for
>   the top blade. Use a wire brush and clean this blade. Remove it and
>   clean the mount, put it back. Next remove the lower blade. To do this
>   safely unplug from the mains. To stop the motor turning while you
>   unscrew place a large flat blade driver next to one of the fins. Clean
>   it all and put it all back together.
>
> Next set the grind to the right courseness. Dose a little onto your
>   hand and rub the grouds with your figer. The grouds should be uniform.
>   If not you need new blades. These shouldnt cost you anymore than
>   £15-20. Makesure you get the right blades as some are right handed &
>   some are left. Don't forget, this grinder is made by Cunill and
>   re-badged iberital so you can get blades from anyone. If your having
>   trouble sourcing new blades leave your number and i'll get a supplier
>   to ring you ASAP.

Comment: Second answer is now marked as "wrong, wrong, wrong" on CofferForums. And having just cleaned an  MC2, I agree.